# JSOUP adding extra encoded stuff for an html

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Actually JSOUP is adding some extra encoded values to my HTML in my jSOUP parser.I am trying to  take care of it by

```
String url = "http://iqtestsites.adtech.de/pictelatest/custombkgd/StylelistDevil.html";
System.out.println("Fetching %s..."+url);

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
//System.out.println(doc.html());

Document.OutputSettings settings = doc.outputSettings();

settings.prettyPrint(false);
settings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.base);
settings.charset("ASCII");
String html = doc.html();
System.out.println(html);
```

But the Entities class is not found for some reason and is giving an error.
My included lib are

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

The original HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="SAF" id="global-header-light">
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div style="background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">                      

<div style="height:2058px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:36px;">


<iframe style="height:90px; width:728px;" />



</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The `doc.html()` from JSOUP gives this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="SAF" id="global-header-light">
 <head> 
  <style>

</style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div style="background-image: url(aol.jpeg); background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:90720;height:720; width:90; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;"> 
   <div style="height:450; width:100; padding-left:681px; padding-top:200px;"> 
    <iframe style="height:1050px; width:300px;"></iframe> &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The iframe element has been added some encoded stuff.

Please help.

Thanks
Swaraj

Comment: What is the original HTML and what does Jsoup add..? The libraries does not really help.

Comment: @DanielB updated the question according to you.

Comment: *But the Entities class is not found for some reason*. If there is a method taking an argument, there must be a way to provide this argument. You might want to check the JSoup version (1.7.2 is the latest) or use code completion in your IDE. `Ctrl+Shift+Double-Space` will give you completion options in Intellij Idea. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev I have update my question to show how I am using the JSOUP parser.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev I have JSOUP 1.7.3 installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually jsoup is not adding the encoded stuff. Jsoup just adds the closing tags that **seem** to be missing. Let me explain.

First of all, jsoup tries to format your html. In your case that means that it will add closing tags that are missing.
**Example**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div>test<span>test");
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   test
   <span>test</span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you check the encoded stuff you will realize that they are closing tags.

```
&lt;/div&gt;  = </div> 
&lt;/div&gt;  = </div>
&lt;/body&gt; = </body>
```

If you go to the site and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (using chrome) then you will see what jsoup
will parse. Chrome will give color to the valid html tags that it recognizes. For some odd reason it won't recognize the tags in the bottom (the same ones that appear with the escaped characters). For the same reason jsoup has a problem with those closing tags too. It doesn't treat them as closing tags, but as text, so it escapes them and then it normalizes the html by adding those tags as I explained earlier.

**EDIT**
I managed to replicate the behavior.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<iframe /><span>test</span>");
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

You can see the exact same behavior. The problem is with the self closing iframe. Making it like this fixes the problem

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<iframe></iframe><span>test</span>");
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

**EDIT 2**
If you want to just receive the html without building the document object you can do this

```
Connection.Response html = Jsoup.connect("http://iqtestsites.adtech.de/pictelatest/custombkgd/StylelistDevil.html").execute();
System.out.println(html.body());
```

Having the above, you can find the self closing iframe and replace it with the valid representation (or remove it completely). Then you can parse that string with `Jsoup.parse()`
This will fix the issue of not recognizing the closing tags after iframe, because it will be valid.

Comment: But it already has closing tags.It is adding more.The div the body and the html are getting closed.

Comment: You are not paying attention. As I mention, the self closing iframe causes the rest of the tags to appear as text. Self closing iframe is not valid html and the result is this unexpected behavior.