# JSoup seems to ignore character codes?

Tags: java, html, regex, arraylist, jsoup

I'm building a small CMS-like application in Java, that takes a .txt file with shirt names/descriptions and loads the names/descriptions into an ArrayList of customShirts (small class I made). Then, it iterates through the ArrayList, and uses JSoup to parse a template (template.html) and insert the unique details of the shirt into the HTML. Finally, it pumps out each shirt into its own HTML file in an output folder.

When the descriptions are loaded into the ArrayList of customShirts, I replace all special characters with the appropriate character codes so they can be properly displayed (for example, replacing apostrophes with ’). The issue is, I've noticed that JSoup seems to automatically turn the character codes into the actual character, which is an issue, since I need the output to be displayable (which requires character codes). Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've looked at other workarounds, like at: [Jsoup unescapes special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368908/jsoup-unescapes-special-characters/34493022#34493022), but they seem to require parsing the file before insertion with replaceAll, and I insert the character-code sensitive text with JSoup, which doesn't seem to make this an option.

Below is the code for the HTML generator I made:

```
public void generateShirtHTML(){

    for(int i = 0; i < arrShirts.size(); i++){

        File input = new File("html/template/template.html");
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        Element title = doc.select("title").first();
        title.append(arrShirts.get(i).nameToCapitalized());

        Element headingTitle = doc.select("h1#headingTitle").first();
        headingTitle.html(arrShirts.get(i).nameToCapitalized());

        Element shirtDisplay = doc.select("p#alt1").first();
        shirtDisplay.html(arrShirts.get(i).name);

        Element descriptionBox = doc.select("div#descriptionbox p").first();
        descriptionBox.html(arrShirts.get(i).desc);
        System.out.println(arrShirts.get(i).desc);

        PrintWriter output;
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter("html/output/" + arrShirts.get(i).URL);
            output.println(doc.outerHtml());
            //System.out.println(doc.outerHtml());
            output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Shirt " + i + " HTML generated!");

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18925448); You can try something like  `doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);`. If that doesn't work, you can try escaping it after getting the HTML from Jsoup, see [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265282) (I read that that's what you want to do, right ? ie. replacing things like quotes with `&quot;` in the output ?). Also - you might want to look into a templating engine like [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/), which would be a more suitable option than Jsoup for this kind of ting.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added     

Document.OutputSettings settings = doc.outputSettings();

    settings.prettyPrint(false);
    settings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
    settings.charset("ASCII");

And it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @JonasCz Please turn your comment into an answer and let OP send the rep you disserve. Next time, don't be shy to post an ANSWER ! Comments are not the place for answers.

Comment: @Stephan , Thanks for the encouragement :-) I didn't post it as an answer because I didn't know if my idea would solve the problem, and I didn't think it was really complete (I also wasn't entirely sure that this was what OP wanted). But I've expanded it into an answer. And, just one more thing: I didn't object to your taking my comment and turning it into an answer (I don't care that much about the rep anyhow..), it just seemed strange to me to take a comment which wasn't complete or meant to answer the question and post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding a little on my comment (since Stephan encouraged me..), you can use

```
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
```

To tell Jsoup to escape / encode special characters in the output, eg. left double quotes (`“`) as `&ldquo;`. To make Jsoup encode *all* special characters, you may also need to add

```
doc.outputSettings().charset("ASCII");
```

In order to ensure that all Unicode special characters will be HTML encoded.

For larger projects where you have to fill in data into HTML files, you can look at using a template engine such as [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) - it's easier to use for this kind of job (less code and such), and it offers many more features specifically for this process. For small projects (like yours), Jsoup is good (I've used it like this in the past), but for bigger (or even small) projects, you'll want to look into some more specialized tools.